# ViewPager findViewById is null in Android <= 4.2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use a ViewPager to have swipe tabs in my app. It works in Android versions above 4.2, but crashes in versions >= 4.0 and <= 4.2.

I get a null pointer exception when I call setAdapter on the view pager and that's because it turns out the view pager is null after findViewById. It works fine in Android versions > 4.2. I can't figure out what the issue is with other Android versions.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

R.layout.activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/profile_list_container">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return new ProfileListFragment();
            case 1:
                return new BoostFragment();
            case 2:
                return new StatsFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, I figured it out. It was using a totally different layout for tablets. I had used the default master/detail template from Android Studio and had forgotten to update the layout for tablets, which explains why my views could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Probably ViewPager is not load correctly in the layout. Check it in the logcat.

Comment: Could you provide more clarity on that? What do you mean by loaded correctly in the layout? I log what mViewPager is when a crash occurs using Crashlytics and it says it is null. Crashes only occur in Android <= 4.2. I can't reproduce it myself. I just see it reported in Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
linearlayout.addView (mViewPager);
```

since you get null ViewPager, 
`new ViewPager(this)` can make sure the problem is not related to the Class of `ViewPager`.

`LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.profile_list_container);` helps you make sure your activity is "connected" to the correct layout.

after you have initialized the ViewPager, remember to set the layoutParam, including width/height...etc

Comment: since you get null ViewPager, `new ViewPager(this)` can make sure the problem is not related to the Class of `ViewPager`.
`LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.profile_list_container);` helps you make sure your activity is "connected" to the correct layout.

after you have initialized the ViewPager, remember to set the layoutParam, including width/height...etc

Comment: Put that in your answer :)

Comment: This really bizarre. I just tried that and now the linearlayout gets a null point exception. Seems like findViewById can't find any views. I even tried first getting the rootView with ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content). That works, but (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_list_container) returns null.

Comment: so if you know the problem is not related to `ViewPager` ,try to remove the code related to ViewPager, before you make any other assumptions on this issue. 
more importantly, try to clean your project in Eclipse (Project - Clean).